# Regex to check preceding and following characters

Tags: regex

i'm struggling to build a working regex to filter all hyphens "-" if and only if the preceding and following characters of the word are [a-zA-Z] without a digit or another hyphen sign.

For example i want to filter the hyphen of this word: Te-st but not for this T3E-st

My current approach is not working yet:

```
([a-zA-Z]+(-)+[\w]+)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use lookarounds:

```
(?<=[a-zA-Z])-(?=[a-zA-Z])
```

This means match `-` if it is preceded and followed by an ASCII letter.

**Update:**

Java doesn't support infinite length lookbehind like `.NET` you can use something like:

```
(?<=^[a-zA-Z]{1,999})-(?=[a-zA-Z]*$)
```

Which will match `-` in `Te-st` but not in `T3E-st`